# The plugin flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle could not be built

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-lifecycle, activity-lifecycle

The task - :compileReleaseJavaWithJavac failed saying: 
The plugin flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle couldn't be built due to the errors:

```java
error: package androidx.lifecycle does not exist
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle;
```

and

```java
error: cannot find symbol
  public static Lifecycle getActivityLifecycle(
                ^
  symbol:   class Lifecycle
  location: class FlutterLifecycleAdapter
```

Here is the FlutterLifecycleAdapter.java file:

```java
package io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.lifecycle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.lifecycle.Lifecycle;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.activity.ActivityPluginBinding;

/** Provides a static method for extracting lifecycle objects from Flutter plugin bindings. */
public class FlutterLifecycleAdapter {
  private static final String TAG = "FlutterLifecycleAdapter";

  /**
   * Returns the lifecycle object for the activity a plugin is bound to.
   *
   * <p>Returns null if the Flutter engine version does not include the lifecycle extraction code.
   * (this probably means the Flutter engine version is too old).
   */
  @NonNull
  public static Lifecycle getActivityLifecycle(
      @NonNull ActivityPluginBinding activityPluginBinding) {
    HiddenLifecycleReference reference =
        (HiddenLifecycleReference) activityPluginBinding.getLifecycle();
    return reference.getLifecycle();
  }
}
```

This is the first time I'm using sharedPreferences and Flutter_secure_storage and the first time I've encountered this problem. 
I believe error came up after I updated Android Studio.
I haven't touched anything in this file.
Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: did you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

**Kindly Follow the below Steps:**

In **gradle-wrapper.properties** add these Below Code:

```
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip
```

[image]

In **gradle.properites** Kindly check the below lines are added:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

[image]

In **android/build.gradle** file add the Below Code:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4'
```

[image]

And check this version in **android/build.gradle**:

```
compileSdkVersion 29
```

[image]

Please refer this Link For More Info:
[clickhere](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/51765)